# Prove that $\ell^p$ and $C[0,1]$ are infinite dimensional

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I think I should use theorem which states that every linear functional from the finite dimensional normed space into normed space is continuous.

But for both of these spaces I can find a linear functional which is not continuous, for example:

$$C[0,1] \ni f \rightarrow \sup_{t\in[0,1]} |(f(t))^2 | \in \mathbb{R}$$
$$\ell^{p} \ni (x_n) \rightarrow \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |x_n|^{2p} \in \mathbb{R}$$

Comment: Hint: such questions can frequently be answered by searching for a simple, infinite set of linearly independent elements. So what kinds of simple continuous functions do you know? What kinds of simple, p-summable sequences do you know?

Comment: as for sequences: $(e_n)$? as for functions: $f_n(x)=x^n$?

Comment: Yes, these give you countably infinite, linearly independent elements in the respective space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you have the theorem that in finite dimension a linear functional is continuous then you could prove that these spaces are not finite dimensional by providing examples of linear functionals that are not continuous.

So your idea is correct. But the problem is that the two examples you give are not linear.

Comment: I completely forgot about this, thanks.

Comment: @luka5z Very glad to help. If you do find an example of a linear discontinuous functional for each space I suggest you post the examples as an answer here. Possibly un-accept this answer and accept your own. I would definitely upvote your answer if you did that.